# get value of <h2> of html page with PHP DOM?

Tags: php

I have a var of a HTTP (craigslist) link `$link`, and put the contents into `$linkhtml`.  In this var is the HTML code for a craigslist page, `$link`.

I need to extract the text between `<h2>` and `</h2>`.  I could use a regexp, but how do I do this with PHP DOM? I have this so far:

```
$linkhtml= file_get_contents($link);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($linkhtml);
```

What do I do next to put the contents of the element `<h2>` into a var `$title`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if `DOMDocument` looks complicated to understand/use to you, then you may try [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) which provides the easiest ever way to parse html.

```
require 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html = '<h1>Header 1</h1><h2>Header 2</h2>';
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
$dom->load( $html );
$title = $dom->find('h2',0)->plaintext; 
echo $title; // outputs: Header 2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code:

```
$linkhtml= file_get_contents($link);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($linkhtml); // loads your html
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$h2text = $xpath->evaluate("string(//h2/text())");
// $h2text is your text between <h2> and </h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with XPath: *untested, may contain errors*

```
$linkhtml= file_get_contents($link);
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($linkhtml);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $xpath->query("/html/body/h2");

if (!is_null($elements)) {
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        $nodes = $element->childNodes;
        foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: before I try it do you mean DOMXpath($dom) or DOMXpath($doc)?

Comment: surely /html/body/h2 - and that assumes the h2 is at the root

Comment: Didn't see your answer, you beat me to it :)

Comment: @ilanco, is it possible to do without loops? There is just 1 "h2" element and I just want the simplest way to do this. thanks