# Simple HTML DOM find tags and fetch data from page link

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Simple HTML DOM find tags and fetch data from page link
Hi I'm Simple HTML DOM,  basically i need to get h2 title and the content from 
the links  (page/id/1). The point I'm getting stack is getting data from page .
The format should be the same that is

1. Title

contet form lik1 ,
content from link5

1. title 2

content from link ,
content from 2

```
   <section class="level">
       <h2> title </h2>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/1">link1 </a>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/2">link2 </a>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/3">link3 </a>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/4">link4 </a>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/5">link5 </a>
   </section>
   <section class="level">
       <h2> title 2 </h2>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/7">link1 </a>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/8">link2 </a>
   </section>
   <section class="level">
       <h2> title 3  </h2>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/9">link2 </a>
       <a class="links" href="page/id/10">link3 </a>
   </section>
```

I  know it should be along these line any help guys

```
   foreach ($html->find('h2') as $key => $value) { 
       echo $html->find('h2',0)->plaintext;
       //this is where Im stack getting the data from the link 
       foreach ( ) {
           echo data from the link example.com/page.php/id/1 
           echo data from the link example.com/page.php/id/2 
       }      
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure of what you want, but have a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524838/get-value-of-h2-of-html-page-with-php-dom

Comment: Ideally it would be `$h2->find('~ a')` but simple html dom doesn't support that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [find](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_find) the `<section>` with the classname `level` using `find('section[class=level]')` Then you could for example loop the childnodes and check the nodeName.

To get only the anchors, you could use `find('section[class=level] a')`

For example:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($data);
$result = $html->find('section[class=level]');
foreach ($result  as $item) {
    foreach($item->childNodes() as $childNode) {
        if ($childNode->nodeName() === "h2") {
            echo $childNode->innertext . "<br>";
        }
        if ($childNode->nodeName() === "a") {
            echo $childNode->getAttribute("href") . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Result

```
 title 
page/id/1
page/id/2
page/id/3
page/id/4
page/id/5
 title 2 
page/id/7
page/id/8
 title 3  
page/id/9
page/id/10
```

Comment: Thanks it is very close to what i was looking for